# Is the sentence grammatically correct? (Concerned with tense usage)

Tags: grammaticality, past-vs-past-perfect

> Since I can understand the English dialogue without much difficulty, there’s no reason not to enjoy the films in the way the film-makers intended.

I'm not sure whether I should use "intended" or "had intended" here, any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Simple past is fine here. You're not establishing up a relationship between an event in the past and one prior to that.

Comment: Check out English Language Learners StackExchange, which has material that will help you choose between past and past perfect with confidence.